# Select rows that are in the range of a know range of dates

Tags: mysql

I know this:

```
$StartDate = '2019-05-01';
$EndDate = '2019-05-30';
```

What would be my error if I would like to select rows that's contain my `$date` in the range of `RAT_DateStart` and `RAT_DateEnd`?

Actually I have this query ?

```
SELECT * FROM ___Rates 
WHERE (RAT_DateStart BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate) 
    OR (RAT_DateEnd BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate);
```

My table is the following:

```
|--------|---------------|-------------|
| RAT_Id | RAT_DateStart | RAT_DateEnd |
|--------|---------------|-------------|
|      1 |    2019-04-10 |  2019-09-24 |
|      2 |    2019-02-03 |  2019-04-15 |
|--------|---------------|-------------|
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want both dates (`$StartDate` and `$EndDate`) to be contained in the range specified by `RAT_DateStart` and `RAT_DateEnd`?

Comment: @Nick, actually the query don't return me any row. It should return me the first one as the know range of dates is is the range of my first row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both start and end dates (`$StartDate` and `$EndDate`) to be contained in the range specified by `RAT_DateStart` and `RAT_DateEnd` then you need to reorganise your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM ___Rates 
WHERE (:StartDate BETWEEN RAT_DateStart AND RAT_DateEnd) 
  AND (:EndDate   BETWEEN RAT_DateStart AND RAT_DateEnd);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
RAT_Id  RAT_DateStart       RAT_DateEnd
1       2019-04-10 00:00:00 2019-09-24 00:00:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fGe7jEAG8EVKGwSToLi87K/0)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Nick's solution is what you're after, but the following is a more typical request...

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM ___Rates
 WHERE :StartDate < RAT_DateEnd
   AND :EndDate   >= RAT_DateStart;
```